# Gradle: How to run build in user defined task?

Tags: java, gradle

i would like to run the build-task from the gradle war plugin inside one of my own defined tasks. I tried various things, but nothing worked.

This is how my task looks at the moment:

```
task deploy << {
    build.execute()
    copy {
        from '/build/libs/app.war'
        into tomcat_webapps
    }
}
```

When i run

```
gradle deploy
```

the build task will not be executed. Does anyone of you know how i can do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling tasks manually should be your very last resort. The gradle way would be to define a dependency between your task and the build task. This way gradle can determine a proper order for the tasks that need to be executed.

Setting up the dependency can be done in several ways. One way would be this:

```
task deploy(type: Copy) {
  dependsOn build

  from '/build/libs/app.war'
  into tomcat_webapps
}
```